# iOS Pragmatically Create Plist with 15 Array Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, object, plist

I hope someone can help, before asking we're using Plist to slimline the whole app. I am creating a plist when somebody selects a player. However what I want to do is create a plist with 15 blank array objects, this way I can just replace and edit as the user goes.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is bad design, why not just use `NSCoding` to save a custom object holding the data to disk. Because saving 15 empty value in an array is just useless. You will have to write code to check the number of items in the array any so why add 15 empty objects to the array in the first place.

Comment: I agree with rckoenes. Create model classes that reflect your data and archive them by implementing the NSCoding protocol on every model class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create plist with 15 arrays you can use:

```
    NSMutableArray * mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        NSArray *array = [NSArray alloc] init];
        [mainArray addObject:array];
    }
    [self saveToFile:mainArray];
```

Method for saving:

```
- (void)saveToFile:(NSArray*)ar
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    [ar writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Very useful thanks, the only useful answer I got, how could I insert blank objects for a set keys?